# Django and Mypy : unable to read config options

Tags: python, django, configuration, mypy

I am attempting to use mypy with django, following the tutorial here:
[django-mypy-check-runs](https://www.ralphminderhoud.com/blog/django-mypy-check-runs/)

I wasn't able to use the **init**.py import as per the article, instead I used the same code in the ready function of the apps.py in my top level app.

mypy runs perfectly, as long as the function api.run has the project base directory in a list as a parameter as per the code in the article:

```
results = api.run([settings.BASE_DIR])
```

I am unable to find out why the project base directory presented this way is of any use.  According to the docs, the list that is passed to api.run, should have configuration options passed in the list as they would be passed to the executable on the commandline.  I have checked the source code of mypy and this seems to be the case.

If I change the code so that the api.run has a list as a parameter, that contains configuration options, mypy doesn't work.  If I pass an empty list or no list at all, mypy doesn't work.

Also, although I have a mypy.ini file in the same directory, and also at the project root (in case this is what the settings.BASE_DIR in the list passed to api.run is supposed to specify), the configuration options in mypy.ini don't seem to be being picked up.

So, how to get the api.run to function and use configuration options from mypy.ini...

MTIA.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it turned out to be quite obvious, documented etc etc.
The api.run command takes the same args as the mypy commandline invocation.  So the following worked for me...

```
results = api.run(['--show-error-codes', settings.BASE_DIR])
```